# How to handle adding a value to first line of txt file that has an existing value using python

Tags: python, file, if-statement, input, file-handling

Looking for help with file handling, please:

So, I'm new to Python, and I decided to go straight for it by writing a small program. Basically, the idea is to have a .txt file that keeps a running balance, on a single line, that is received from user input. However, I am struggling to understand how to write the user input into the value on the single line. With that said, this is what I have to offer for reference:

```
print("\n"""" Please choose an option: 
    Balance:
        1. View
        2. Update
    -------------    
    Savings: 
        3. View
        4. Update""""\n") 
number = int(input(" Enter a number: ")) 
if number == 1:
    view = open("current_balance.txt", "r")
    print("\n", "Balance: " + view.read())
elif number == 2: 
    new_entry = input("\n" + " Enter figure: ")  
    update_balance = open("current_balance.txt", "a+")          
    update_balance.write(new_entry)
    update_balance = open("current_balance.txt", "r")
    print(update_balance.read())
    update_balance.close()
elif number == 3:
    print("test")
elif number == 4: 
    print("test")
```

If it is not too much to ask, some general guidance would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to overwrite the existing data you can use 'w' instead of 'a+'. 'w' overwrites while 'a+' appends to the end of the file.

Comment: I see, so the difference between `a+` and `w` is that `a+` adds something new and `w` writes over something that all ready exist?

Comment: Precisely. Only time they will act the same is when the file is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand

- `View`: Should display the balance (Stored as the first line of the file)
- `Update`: Should add the User input value with existing balance value and write the sum of these two as the first line.

Here is the code that you need.

```
print("\n"""" Please choose an option: 
    Balance:
        1. View
        2. Update
    -------------    
    Savings: 
        3. View
        4. Update""""\n") 
number = int(input(" Enter a number: ")) 
if number == 1:
    view = open("current_balance.txt", "r")
    print("\n", "Balance: " + view.read())
    view.close()
elif number == 2: 
    new_entry = input("\n" + " Enter figure: ") 
    update_balance = open("current_balance.txt", "r")
    
    # The first line of the file - Existing Balance
    existing_val = update_balance.read()
    
    update_balance = open("current_balance.txt", "w")
    # If the first line is not empty, Add User's input value and existing value and write the sum to the file.
    if existing_val != "":
        value = int(new_entry) + int(existing_val)
        update_balance.write(str(value) + '\n')
    else:
        update_balance.write(new_entry)
    
    update_balance = open("current_balance.txt", "r")
    print(update_balance.read())
    update_balance.close()
elif number == 3:
    print("test")
elif number == 4: 
    print("test")
```

Comment: Thanks, Ram. Tried this out and works great. However, I have a question about the line `update_balance.write(str(value) + '\n')`: I don't understand how to read it, specifically because it has `str` and not `int`, and I thought `\n` meant a new line? As well, I do see that it does not work without it, so do you did not mind explaining that, please?

Comment: To try to join an `int` with a `str` you need to convert it to `str` too. So value is converted to `str` and then concatenated with `\n`.

Comment: Hi @SaatvikRamani, are you free to answer a quick question relating to this same code, please?

Comment: Sure. How can I help?

Comment: Thank you, and don't feel you have to answer either, but I would be grateful if you could even just suggest resources, please. As well, this may be convoluted, but I'm sure these are very noob of me to ask you: firstly, why when using `,` with `\n`  in `print` it causes an extra space on the next line but not when used with `+` to concatenate it? Also, is it best to just use `\n` within the `print` quotations, such as `print("\nExample")`? Lastly, why does `input` produce a `TypeError` when using the `,` with `\n`, such as `input("\n", "str")`, but not with `+`, such as `input("\n" + "str")` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to write the new balance on a new line, while keeping track of the old balances. What you can do is the following

```
print("\n"""" Please choose an option: 
    Balance:
        1. View
        2. Update
    -------------    
    Savings: 
        3. View
        4. Update""""\n")
number = int(input(" Enter a number: "))
if number == 1:
    view = open("current_balance.txt", "r")
    print("\n", "Balance: " + view.read())
elif number == 2:
    new_entry = input("\n" + " Enter figure: ")
    update_balance = open("current_balance.txt", "a")
    update_balance.write(new_entry + "\n")
    update_balance = open("current_balance.txt", "r")
    balances= list(map(int, update_balance.readlines()))
    total_balance = sum(balances)
    print(balances, "\n", total_balance)
    update_balance.close()
elif number == 3:
    print("test")
elif number == 4:
    print("test")
```

Comment: I suppose with that I could then sum up the values and print the total, but I was hoping to just add to the current value as an addition. So, if the balance in the file is 10 on the first line, and the user enters 5 to update the balance, the total balance of the file would be 15, by adding 5 to 10 on the same line. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, makes sense. See modified code. Although Ram answered what you initially asked for, this is an alternative to also have some data management.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help. I'll consider both.